# Getting task_id inside a Celery task

Tags: python, object, celery

This is probably a stupid question but its got me stumped coming from a Ruby background.

I have an object that looks like this when I try to print it.

```
print celery.AsyncResult.task_id
>>><property object at 0x10c383838>
```

I was expecting the actual value of the task_id property to be printed here. How do I get to the actual value?

**UPDATE 1**

```
@celery.task
def scan(host):
    print celery.AsyncResult.task_id
    cmd = 'ps -ef'
    cm = shlex.split(cmd)
    scan = subprocess.check_output(cm)
    return scan
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Create an instance of the class. `property`s are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) that are used to provide attribute-like access to getter/setter methods, but they work at the instance level. When accessing them from the class you simply get the `property` wrapper.

Comment: @Bakuriu you should actually post this as an answer :)

Comment: From the letter-casing and output it looks like `celery.AsyncResult` must be the name of a class, not an instance of one, and `task_id` is a property attribute of that class -- which is what Bakuriu is saying I believe.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short story, within function `scan`, use `scan.request.id`.

See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=request#task-request-info

Comment: Yes I think I tried that but it didn't work within the context of the worker. I'll try it again though!

Comment: What version of Celery are you using?  For older version (I think before 2.2) there was a different way to do it using keyword parameters.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.23 (Chiastic Slide)

Comment: Hmm - Well I'm blown! It works now! Thanks Chris! As simple as scan.request.id

Comment: For me, using `celery.current_task.request.id` inside the task worked

Answer (score 25):

In order to make your tasks more "OO-like", you could use the `bind` argument to get a reference to `self`:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def scan(self, host):
  print self.request.id
```

Please note that `self.request.id` is actually an instance of `AsyncTask`. In order to have the task id as a **string**, you should do `self.request.id.__str__()`.

From [Celery's documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context) (after the example):

> The `bind` argument means that the function will be a “bound method” so that you can access attributes and methods on the task type instance.

Comment: `self.request.id` is a string, checked it right now with celery `5.2.1`. The [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=request#task-request) seem to agree.

Answer (score 17):

You are accessing the [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) from the class, while `task_id` is a property of *instances* of `AsyncResult`.

To obtain the value of `task_id` you first have to create an instance of that class, afterwards accessing `async_result_instance.task_id` will return you the real id.

In your updated code:

```
@celery.task
def scan(host):
    print celery.AsyncResult.task_id
    # ...
```

Here you are accessing the class as I've already explained. What you want is an instance of the currently executing task. You might use [`celery.current_task`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.current_task) to get the currently executing task-object:

```
@celery.task
def scan(host):
    print celery.current_task.task_id
```

Or, if you are interested in the unique id use the [`request`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=request#Task.request) attribute of the decorated function:

```
@celery.task
def scan(host):
    print scan.request.id
    cmd = 'ps -ef'
    cm = shlex.split(cmd)
    # IMPORTANT: Do *not* use "scan = ..."!
    result = subprocess.check_output(cm)
    return result
```

In this second case do *not* use any local variable called `scan` otherwise you'll an `UnboundLocalError`.

(Code not tested since I don't have `celery` installed.)

---

The `property`s are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) used to provide attribute-like access to getter/setter methods, so that you can access data like:

```
instance.attribute
instance.attribute = value
```

But when the code is executed the setter or getter can control what's going on.

You can verify this with a dummy class:

```
>>> class Dummy(object):
...     @property
...     def a(self):
...             print("called the getter!")
...             return 1
... 
>>> Dummy.a
<property object at 0x7fdae86978e8>
>>> Dummy().a
called the getter!
1
```

Comment: Hmm..I tried your example above and it makes sense. However within the context of the Celery worker it does not work. I think because the celery.AsyncResult class has already been created. So I guess I need to use something like 'self' ?