# How to get Task ID in celery django from the currently running Shared Task itself?

Tags: django, django-views, celery

In my `views.py` I am using celery to run a shared task present in `tasks.py`.

Here is how I call from `views.py`

```
task = task_addnums.delay()
task_id = task.id
```

`tasks.py` looks as

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult


@shared_task
def task_addnums():
   # print self.request.id
   # do something
    return True
```

Now, as we can see we already have task_id from `task.id` in `views.py` . But, Let's say If I want to fetch task id from the shared_task itself how can I ? The goal is to get task id from the `task_addnums` itself so I can use that to pass into some other function. 
I tried using `self.request.id` considering the first param is `self` . But it didn't worked.

Comment: You can't get it from `task_addnums` - that is simple function. You need to store that id somehow - in cache or pass as parameter in the context.

Comment: How could I pass in that as a parameter. It gets assigned after the delay() is called. You have any ideas @Chiefir

Comment: You need to show more of your view and where u want to pass task.id

Comment: I need `task id` accessible from within `task_addnums` itself. The reason is that, because I will be passing that task id into a function which I call from `task_addnums()` . So, the task_id in views.py is useless @Chiefir

Comment: I solved it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872854/getting-task-id-inside-a-celery-task helps

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

This answer is a gem [Getting task_id inside a Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872854/getting-task-id-inside-a-celery-task)

You can do `function_name.request.id` to get task id.

Answer (score 3):

`current_task` from celery will get the current task.Code like this:

```
from celery import shared_task, current_task

@shared_task
def task_addnums():
    print(current_task.request)
    # do something
    return True
```